# C#:Managed Extensibility Framework in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mef

I have implemented **MEF(Managed Extensibility Framework)** in my **WPF** Application using `System.ComponentModel.Composition`

Since `System.ComponentModel.Composition` is not present in WinRT.

How do i implement it or does MEF even exist in Winrt or not??

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install the MEF NuGet Package.

In the Package Manager Console:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Composition

And use the `System.Composition` namespace instead.